# Dynamic configuration does not work with spring boot property when it is assigned a value in the application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, azure, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, azure-app-configuration

I have been dealing with an issue for a while. I have a spring boot application which I need to integrate with azure application configuration store to dynamically change the properties without restarting the application. Before I explain the issue, here is my setup,

I have following dependencies added in the pom.xml along with
azure-spring-cloud-appconfiguration-config-web:2.11.0,

[Spring Cloud dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0xgs.png)

[Spring Boot dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh6vK.png)

Here is my java class annotated with @Configuration and @RefreshScope,

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class CustomConfiguration {

  // property assigned a value  in the application.properties as "version=0.0"
  // property has also been assigned a valuein azure app config store as "version=1.0"
  @Value("${version}")
  private String version;

  // property only assigned value in the azure appconfig store as "test=1.0"

  @Value("${test}")
  private String test;
   
  public String getTest() {
       return test;
  }
    
  public String getVersion() {
       return version;
   }
}
```

Here is my bootstrap.properties,

```
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.name=appName
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].enabled = true
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].connection-string=<Connection String>
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].selects[0].key-filter=/appName/
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].selects[0].label-filter=
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.triggers[0].key=/appName/sentinel
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.refresh-interval= 5s
```

The issue that I have been experiencing is with a property("version") when it is assigned a value in the application.properties. When a property assigned a value in the application.properties, it does not read value from the azure app configuration. I have another property ("test") which is only assigned value in azure app config store.

When the application is started with this setup, "version" property takes the value from the applicaiton.properties and "test" property takes the value from azure app config store. Also, as I change the sentinel key after modifying other properties ("version", "test") in the azure app configuration, it generates refresh event and recognizes that "version" and "test" properties have been changed. However, it only updates "test" property value and "version" property remain the same as assigned in applciation.properties when it refreshes the spring-boot context.

Can someone help me understand this behavior?

For troubleshooting this issue, I have tried following,

I have compared the maven dependency tree with another application which works as expected (property that has been assigned value in Azure app configuration store overrides the value that is assigned in application.properties) to check if there are any version/artifact discrepancies.

Tried debugging both the application and compared debug logs to identify any difference.

Above troubleshooting steps did not help as the maven dependency tree was showing the same dependencies and the versions. Also, the debug logs were almost similar.

Here is the output of "env" endpoint from spring actuator. This shows that the default value in application.properties is overriding the property in the azure app configuration,

```
{
    "activeProfiles": [
        "dev"
    ],
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "server.ports",
            "properties": {
                "local.server.port": {
                    "value": 8080
                }
            }
        },
        {
        "name":"bootstrapProperties-/myapp/<azure-app-store-link>{
            "properties": {
                "appconfig.version": {
                    "value": "1.0"
                },
                "sentinel": {
                    "value": "11"
                },
                "test": {
                    "value": "1.0"
                },
                "feature-management.featureManagement": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Config resource 'file [path\\to\\application.properties]' via location 'path/to'",
            "properties": {
                "appconfig.version": {
                    "value": "0.0",
                    "origin": "URL [file:path/to/application.properties] - 313:19"
                },
                "test": {
                    "value": "0.0",
                    "origin": "URL [file:path/to/application.properties] - 314:6"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "class path resource [application.properties]:class path resource [application.properties]",
            "properties": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code even compile with the `#` instead of `//` for line comments?

Comment: As I'm working with Rutul, I can tell you that that line was just added in this posting, it's not in the code.

Comment: @Robert, Hi, thanks for your response. As David mentioned, these comments were just added here for better understanding. However, I edited my post to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the same dependencies which you used.
in **pom.xml**.

```
    <groupId>com.configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleapp1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sampleapp1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-cloud-appconfiguration-config-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please check my sample **CustomConfiguration.**

```
package com.configuration.sampleapp1;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@RefreshScope

public class CustomConfiguration {

    @Value("${myapp.version}")
    private String version;

    @Value("${myapp.apiKey}")
    private String apiKey;

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }
}
```

Please check the below snippet for more understanding.

[image]

Then I configured the **Application.properties** with below for test.

```
# Custom Application Properties  
myapp.version=2.11.0  
myapp.apiKey=abc123
```

- Then I created Azure app configuration in portal. I am able to get the Key-value from the app configuration successfully.
  [image]

**Result :**
[image]

- I took the connection string into **bootstrap.properties** to connect with my spring boot application.
- I am able to get the assigned value's from the **application.properties**

**Result :**
[image]

**Monitored:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see You removed `@RefreshScope` annotation from the CustomConfiguration.java. Does it refresh the property when you update it into azure app configuration without restarting the app?

Comment: @RutulBhojak I apologies for the wrong code snippet I added by mistakenly please check my updated code in the above answer.

Comment: @RutulBhojak, Yes after once I started running the application it connects with the AAC that reflected in the monitoring result picture then after without restarting the application I am able to get the values which I configured because of the AAC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The same code does not work with my app. I am looking for an explanation on what could be the issue. Initially, I thought there may be a dependency issue, however, upon checking the dependency tree with another app that works fine, it did not reveal any discrepancies.  I also debug both app and compared the generated logs. That too did not explain why it would be not working.
Want to know how `@RefreshScope` works so that I can better understand the issue.

Comment: Check that you are triggering the refresh event correctly. By default, you can use the **/actuator/refresh** endpoint exposed by Spring Boot Actuator to initiate a refresh.

Comment: I use azure sentinel key to trigger the refresh, `spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.triggers[0].key=/appName/sentinel`

Comment: I updated the post to show the output from "env" actuator endpoint. this shows that it is able to see both the values. one form the application.properties and from azure app config store. somehow application.properties is overriding it.

Comment: `@RefreshScope` allows the Spring beans to get refreshed when there is a change in the configuration properties. It means that when a refresh event is triggered, the bean instances annotated with @RefreshScope, including in my CustomConfiguration bean, It is re-initialized with updated property values.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the root cause of this issue. It turned out to be `customPrtopertySource.java` class in the codebase. This class was adding application.properties as `ReloadablePropertySource` to the spring environment property sources. This was making application to give higher precedence to `applicaiton.properties` than any other sources.